# "Is missing" vs. "is missed"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, past-participles, present-participles

I was wondering why we say "something is missing" instead of "something is missed"?

If *missed* is an adjective then why we use it that way?

E.g.: "The sword is missing".

Comment: *"The sword is missing"* and *"the sword is missed"* mean different things.

Comment: The sword is missed means what Peter?

Comment: *Missing* = "I don't have it". *Missed* = "I have a longing for it".

Comment: when doing the inspection, 'the sword was missed.' not is missed

Comment: And then we have "the sword missed" which could leave you open to a deadly attack...

Comment: If you have to ask what that phrase means, then you might find the [ell.se] Stack Exchange a community worth checking out. @Rory - _The sword is missing_ could mean that, too, as in: "The sword is missing every time I swing it."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Imagine you have a collection of objects including a sword, one day you can't see the sword and you don't know where it's gone, then you can say "*The sword is missing*", meaning it's absent.

Now imagine you had a sword and you gave it to someone, or you got rid of it, the point being you know where it's gone and you don't have it. You see a snake in your lounge and you wish you had your sword to cut its head, you miss the sword and you think "*the sword is missed*" (passive).